# php не подключается к db2. Ошибка лицензии SQL1598N

Tags: php, pdo, db2, ibm, centos7

Есть сервер CentOS 7.3 c Apache и 7.1.8 php БЕЗ доступа в инет. Задача - выгрузка данных из удалённой DB2 базы, к которой никакого доступа, кроме как к хранимым НЕТ.

Моя очерёдность действий:

1) Ставлю DB2 connect 10.5, лицензирую его (есть официальная лицензия)

2) Собираю руками (т.к. нет инета) либы ibm_db2.so и pdo_ibm.so из исходников согласно официальной документации с сайта php.net (с указанием пути до установленного DB2 connect'а)

Либы компилятся нормально, в модулях отображаются. При специальной попытке залогиниться с неверными данными - выпадает ошибка, что данные неверные и отвергнуты сервером, что есть хорошо, значит коннект к базе есть и дрова работают.

Однако при правильных данных мне выкидывается ошибка:

> SQL1598N An attempt to connect to the database server failed because
>   of a licensing problem.

[Официальная документация IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01598n.html) по этому поводу говорит - 
мол лицензия не активирована(или её нет на этом компьютере), хотя она точно ставилась и точно активировалась с сообщением -

> This product is now licensed for use...

Кто-нибудь тут сталкивался с подобным? Куда копать дальше?

Пробовал до этого (был полный снос ОС после этого) ставить просто драйвера для пхп, без лицензий и полного клиента DB2, но получал абсолютно такую же ошибку.